# Can I have multiple wlan cards on one PC and connect to multiple connections?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet-connection

Can I have multiple wlan cards on one PC and connect to multiple connections? Is it possible connect to 2 or more wlan connection and use the internet with improved speed?

For example i have one 2Mb/Sec Internet and one 5Mb/sec internet connection. Is it possible that I can connect to both at a time and use at 7Mb/secc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I have multiple wlan cards on one PC and connect to multiple connections?

Yes absolutely, but it probably won't be as useful, or as easy to setup as you are hoping it will be.

> Is it possible connect to 2 or more wlan connection and use the internet with improved speed?

It depends on the Operating System.  On Windows/Mac OSX this is nearly impossible.  Under [Linux it is only very difficult](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html).

> For example i have one 2Mb/Sec Internet and one 5Mb/sec internet connection. Is it possible that I can connect to both at a time and use at 7Mb/secc?

Any possible solution is going to load balance the connections, so if you are downloading 2 things, and where connected, each download might use a separate connection.  But if you are only downloading a single file it will only cross one of the links.

Answer (score 1):

If you load balance the connections, you'll likely see an improved speed for applications like BitTorrent (where you maintain a connection to each peer) and download accelerators (those that handle multiple connections, at least) - both of those could have connections on each link.

I haven't done this in-OS myself, but there are hardware solutions to accomplish the same goal (one router sitting in front of two modems). This will enable Windows/Mac computers to utilize both connections as well, and might be a better solution, depending on your requirements.