# can i use 2 4G LTE on one pc?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My question is similar to, however I'm using a 4G SIM and router that receives 4G signal and sends to PC via LAN:

- [Can I have multiple wlan cards on one PC and connect to multiple connections?](https://superuser.com/questions/391281/can-i-have-multiple-wlan-cards-on-one-pc-and-connect-to-multiple-connections)

Can I add another connection from another 4G receiver, like this: 
 [image: 4Greceiver]

Comment: It is possible, however if your purpose for doing so is to aggregate throughput, you'll need an OS that makes that possible _(generally a hardware or software router since aggregating WAN really should be done via a hardware/software router)_

Comment: If you want to provide a better speed for multiple users/downloads this can be done (each connection is getting assigned to one of the available Internet connections). However if you want to speed-up one single download you need channel bonding which means you additionally need a service provider on the Internet which receives both channels and combines them.

Comment: @Robert I am using for more stable internet .should i select second 4G sim with different provider?

Comment: Simple answer is yes you can, just as well as you can use two network links. The clarification here should be what are you trying to accomplish with two links, faster speeds, more connections, dedicated connections for X purpose, etc? The reality is that if you are trying to do link aggregation or bonding, the answer is no because not only is that technology required on your end, it has to be supported by the far end as well.